# DateTimePicker selected Date

Tags: c#, wpf, wpftoolkit

I am using the extended WPF-Toolkit for this DateTimePicker.
I want to give it a minimum and a maximum date which already works fine.
But when i now click on the picker, the current date is selected.
Do you have any tips for me on how to autoselect the minimum date on default?

I already set both, the **DefaultValue** and the **Value** to the **Minimum** and it still does not work.

Comment: you must have something like selecteddate property. why don't you just automatically set it to minimum date?

Comment: Did you try setting the [DefaultValue](https://wpftoolkit.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=DateTimePicker)?

Comment: I set both, the DefaultValue and the Value to the Minimum and it still does not work

Comment: Please update the question with what you tried so far. It doesn't help if we have to ask for things you tried one by one

Comment: Is the WPF-Toolkit still needed for this ? In .Net 4 and above I think this is a native control, no ?

Comment: @AFract +1. Looking at the toolkit's DateTimePicker's source for the SelectedValue property and still haven't found it